# Specify max loop of tweenlite in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

```
    public function tweenLetterReward(totalReward:int):void {

        var prizeAr:Vector.<String> = new < String > ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4",
                                                      "str5"];
        for (var i:int = 0; i < totalReward; i++) 
        {
            //rewardText.visible = true;
            TweenLite.to(rewardText, (.5+i*1), { y:150, onComplete:function(_i:int):void {
                rewardText.y = 300;
                rewardText.text = prizeAr[_i];
                tweenLetterReward(_i);
                //rewardText.visible = false;
            }, onCompleteParams:[i]});
        }
    }
```

In the code above, assume i call tweenLetterReward(3);
In onComplete function, I trace the _i value. Why it becomes descending or _i = 2,1,0. It should be 0,1,2. Please help. Thanks

Comment: You seem to be using a mix of iteration and recursion and I think you probably want to choose one or the other. Could you explain what it is you're trying to achieve and then somebody should be able to point you in the right direction?

Comment: i just want to get the "_i" value ascending from 0 to 2 in onComplete function.

Comment: When you run your loop, each iteration writes over the previous Tween you've set up on rewardText so only the last tween is actually executed (in your example _i is 2). When that tween completes you call your function again using _i as the parameter for totalReward and the process is repeated. That's why you're getting the results you're seeing, but without an idea of what you're attempting to do visually, it's difficult to give you pointers on how to fix it. My hunch would be that you want to look at the delay property if you're using a loop, or use recursion, but not both.